# Vue JS - Display data if two strings from two different json arrays match

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my Vue JS app I would like to display a div only if two strings match form two different json arrays.

I'm using Axios to get the two different json endpoints combining them into two arrays and displaying the data in a view.

The strings that should match are the following

```
[
  {
    "info": [
      {
        "uuid": "888"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
[
  {
    "postId": "888"
  }
]
```

I'm posting the uuid in a view using a loop

```
<div v-for="posts in $route.params.post.postdata" :key="post.uuid">
<p>{{ post.uuid }}</p>
</div>
```

and the post id by

```
<div v-for="special in specials" :key="special.postId">
<p>{{ special.postId }}</p>
```

My details view

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    specials () {
      return this.$store.state.specials
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.loading = true
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchPosts')
      .then(specials => {
        this.loading = false
      })
  }
}
```

Would I need a method and a `v-if`?

Comment: please give more details about the 2 arrays

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim The info array is nested (object inside object) and the post array is structured more simply, did you need the complete json object? I stripped it down to make it easier to see the only strings I need to match.

Comment: please post the relevant parts of the json file and where are you getting them

Comment: _"I would like to display a div only if two strings match"_  what `<div>`? Given you're dealing with two arrays, it's very unclear what you're trying to do. How are your two template snippets related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some naming mismatches in your example and we don't know what the route params correlate with.  `info` is not explicitly used anywhere, and it's unclear what layout you are trying for. But here's my guess, assuming that the outer loop represents `info`

```html
<div v-for="post in $route.params.post.postdata" :key="post.uuid">
   {{ post.uuid }}
   <template v-for="special in specials">
      <p v-if="post.uuid == special.postId">{{ special }}</p>
   </template>
</div>
```